# Using NSColorWell with different windows

Tags: objective-c, macos

Im trying to make `NSColorWell` to be used in all open `NSWindows` with `CustomView` .I'm using the following code to create new windows:

```
- (IBAction)createWindows:(id)pId {
       MyWindowController *zWindowController =
    [[MyWindowController alloc]
     initWithWindowNibName:@"MyExtraWindow"];
    nsPointWindowOrigin.x   += 100.0;
    nsPointWindowOrigin.y   += 15.0;

    [zWindowController.window setFrameOrigin:nsPointWindowOrigin];
    [zWindowController showWindow:self];
    [nsMutaryOfWindows addObject:zWindowController];
}
```

in here `MyExtraWindow` string is a .xib file name which holds `NSWindow` with `CustomView` any ideas how I can make `NSColorwell` to work with all new created windows?

Comment: Not able to understand your question. Where/How are you using the color well in your current window. What are the problems you are facing?

Comment: Im creating painting program i have NSPanel With NSColorwell in ToolPallete.xib file and i want to use NSColorWell color to draw in CustomView which is in MyExtraWindow.xib file

Comment: and my problem is that i cannot connect NSColorWell with CustomView because they are in different .xib files

Comment: You need to get the color well to the other xib or just need to get the color value from the color well and use it in the other xib?

Comment: I need to get the color value from the color well and use it in the other xib

Comment: if i put NSColorWell in the same xib everything is fine because i can connect NSColorWell to CustomView, but i need to make NSColorWell in another xib because i have one NSColorWell which is used by all opened   Windows and created windows

Comment: This is no different from passing around any values between objects right? You can declare an instance variable for the color well to accept the color wherever you are using. Its just a matter of getting the right objects and passing the color value.

Comment: So I guess you can have variables to hold a reference to this color well in all the places where you need it and initialize this with the color well value when initializing itself so that you can get the color value later.

Comment: I have an IBOutlet NSColorWell *Colorwell; connected to my NSColorWell and this part of code which is in CustomView.m file is getting color from NSColorWell:                                                 CIColor *cicolor = [[CIColor alloc] initWithColor:[Colorwell color]];
            [brushFilter setValue:cicolor forKey:@"inputColor0"];

Comment: it should be ok i think but i get this error when i try to draw on customView CIRadialGradient apply:: Caught exception: CIRadialGradient: colorRadialShading: nil value for argument #2 (c0)

Comment: I wouldn't know without knowing the code being written. Anyway the key here is since the NSPanel is needed through out your application keep it handy. i.e maybe pass it around,like whenever you initialise the window controllers have a reference in it that will point to the panel (or if just the colour well then to that).

Comment: thanks for help! I will try what you are suggesting